# Transform uint64_t range in uint32_t range

Tags: c++, c++20

I want transform an uint64_t into an uintw_t with w in { 8, 16, 32} preserving "range":

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>
```

Idea 1:

f:[a,b]->[c,d] with f(a)=c, f(b)=d

let a = 0, b = 2^64-1, c = 0 and d = 2^w-1.

if f(x) = mx+n with m = (d-c)/(b-a) = (2^w-1)/(2^64-1) < 1 (we need float or double...), n = 0

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_unsigned_v <T>, T>::type = 0>
T transform_a(uint64_t n)
{
   constexpr double factor = static_cast<double>(~T(0)) / ~uint64_t(0);
   return static_cast<T>( factor*n );
}

template<>
uint64_t transform_a(uint64_t n)
{
   return n;
}
```

Don't work with uint16_t :c.

*Idea 2:

Don't work correctly, i wrongly tested it with 0xffffffffffffffffull...

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_unsigned_v <T>, T>::type = 0>
T transform_b(uint64_t n)
{
     return static_cast<T>(n);
}
```

It cuts the number to its lower bits.

Idea 3:

Group bytes and remap with idea 1. For example 0xabcabcab in uint32_t to uint16_t:

abca -> [x] cabc -> [y] with ffff--> ff and 0000--> 00

Idea 4:

Right shift (CHAR_BIT = 8...)

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_unsigned_v <T>, T>::type = 0>
T transform_c(uint64_t n)
{
     return static_cast<T>(n>>(64 - 8*sizeof(T)));
}

template<>
uint64_t transform_c(uint64_t n)
{
   return n;
}
```

This idea makes the most sense to me, however it rules out the effect of minor bits without any weighting or rounding.

https://quick-bench.com/q/Vs1W4UP35MCpJo5pY1ebXnM7QNo

In "real usage" double and shift versions are equivalent for uint32_t
In "individual use without context" shift version is faster for uint32_t

> My main question would be, what is the most usual in this type of conversions?

> As an additional question, is there any efficient way to perform this process with some kind of rounding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shifting is standard; you can get some simple rounding by first **adding half** of the least-significant preserved bit’s value before shifting, although that doesn’t implement proper round-to-even and you have to worry about overflow.